# I have lost my Samsung Galaxy Ace

Tags: gps, samsung-galaxy-ace, lost-phone

2 days ago, I misplaced my Samsung Galaxy Ace in my room. I had woken up (It charged the whole night so it had 100% charge), and put it somewhere in my room. The thing is, I think I turned it off. Even if it was on, none of my sounds were on. Also my GPS isn't turned on. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

If it's turned off, you most certainly can not turn it on remotely, do there's no helping you.

If it's turned on, you could try activating an alarm from Google device manager, if you didn't deactivate it earlier. Go to [Google device manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) and click "alarm"; the sound may help you find your phone. The GPS data indoors is very inaccurate so it is of no use; it would only tell you it's in your room, which you already know.

Comment: Dont worry I found it !